# Retrieve result based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I'm currently trying to write a `SELECT` statement from 3 tables using `JOIN`. But I can't seem to get the select statement to output the  values that I want to from the 3 tables

This is an example of what makes up my tables:

> Applicant table
> APPNUM     APPNAME
>
> ---
>
> A0001      Derrick Tan
> A0002      Eugene Loh
> A0003      Samuel Lim
> A0004      Ann Chan
> A0005      Jourdan Wee
> A0006      Linda Koh
> A0007      Veronica Lim
> A0008      Junaida Bte Ismail
> A0009      Gene Tan
> A0010      Rupesh Subramaniam
> A0011      Muhammad Farid
>
> Skillpossessed table
> SKILLPOSAP SKILLPOSSKILL
>
> ---
>
> A0001      SK001
> A0001      SK003
> A0001      SK005
> A0001      SK006
> A0001      SK201
> A0001      SK301
> A0002      SK107
> A0002      SK108
> A0002      SK202
>
> Skillneeded table
> SKILLNEEDE SKILLNEEDEDSKILL
>
> ---
>
> P0001      SK001
> P0001      SK005
> P0001      SK006
> P0001      SK201
> P0001      SK301

As you can see I need to retrieve the values appnum and appname from Applicant based on a skillneededposnum value from Skillneeded. So the link is from Skillneeded to Skillpossessed to Applicant. Using `JOIN`, I can retrieve the appnum n appnames but they are duplicated values!

This is the Select statement:

```
SELECT APPNUM,APPNAME
FROM APPLICANT A
LEFT JOIN SKILLPOSSESSED B
ON A.APPNUM = B.SKILLPOSAPPNUM
LEFT JOIN SKILLNEEDED C
ON B.SKILLPOSSKILL = C.SKILLNEEDEDSKILL
WHERE C.SKILLNEEDEDPOSNUM = 'P0001';
```

This is an example of the results:

> APPNUM       APPNAME
>
> ---
>
> A0001       Derrick Tan
> A0001       Derrick Tan
> A0001       Derrick Tan
> A0001       Derrick Tan
> A0001       Derrick Tan
> A0003       Samuel Lim
> A0003       Samuel Lim
> A0003       Samuel Lim
> A0004       Ann Chan
> A0004       Ann Chan
> A0005       Jourdan Wee

The displayed result should only be a SINGLE ROW of `A0001 Derrick Tan`.

**EDIT**: The process is from skillneeded to skillprocessed to applicant. 'P0001' will get the 5 'SK---' data from the skillneeded table. From there the 5 'SK---' data will retrieve the 'A0001' from the skillprocessed table. Lastly 'A0001' will retrieve the name from the applicant table.

How should I modify my existing sql statement to achieve this? Or is there a better way to doing this other than using `JOIN`?

Appreciate all the help!

Comment: I don't really understand your expected output. Mainly because I don't see a sample input. What data should the tables contain in order to result in that single row you mention? Also can you explain in plain english what is the process you perform to get the output you need?

Comment: If you simply want to remove duplicates in the result, you can add `DISTINCT`: `SELECT DISTINCT APPNUM, APPNAME ...`

Comment: You simply need a group by statement. Or post the schema

Comment: @GuillaumePoussel Well not only to remove the duplicates but also to display ONLY the result based on the 'SK---' values.

Comment: Does the recommended select distinct or group by not work for you?  If so, I think you need to give us more information about your desired output.

Comment: @Andrew I believe that distinct would be work for me. But that would still result in other values such as 'A0003','A0004', and 'A0005' being displayed since ONLY 'A0001' should be display when it has all 5 'SK---' data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
SELECT Applicant.APPNUM, Applicant.APPNAME, COUNT(*) AS SkillCount
FROM Applicant
  INNER JOIN Skillpossessed ON Applicant.APPNUM = Skillpossessed.SKILLPOSAP
  INNER JOIN Skillneeded ON Skillpossessed.SKILLPOSSKILL = Skillneeded.SKILLNEEDEDSKILL
WHERE Skillneeded.SKILLNEEDE = 'P0001'
GROUP BY Applicant.APPNUM
ORDER BY SkillCount DESC;
```

It would give output of:

```
APPNUM  APPNAME      SKILLCOUNT
A0001   Derrick Tan  5
```

Basically, it finds applicants who already have skills that are listed in the Skillsneeded table and shows how many skills from that table they possess.  It uses Group By to get a single line per applicant, and then sorts descending to put those with the most skills at the top.  In this case, the only applicant with any skills from the Skillsneeded table is Derrick Tan, so he is the only result.

SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58d67/17

**EDIT** - To get only the results where the SkillCount is 5, you could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Applicant.APPNUM, Applicant.APPNAME, COUNT(*) AS SkillCount
      FROM Applicant
        INNER JOIN Skillpossessed ON Applicant.APPNUM = Skillpossessed.SKILLPOSAP
        INNER JOIN Skillneeded ON Skillpossessed.SKILLPOSSKILL = Skillneeded.SKILLNEEDEDSKILL
      WHERE Skillneeded.SKILLNEEDE = 'P0001'
      GROUP BY Applicant.APPNUM) T1
WHERE SkillCount = 5;
```

SQL Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58d67/22

Comment: Erm the code works fine. But it will also display other appnum when they also have any of the 'SK---' data. How do I do it such that the statement only returns the result that has ALL 5 'SK---' data?

Comment: Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I thought of that, but wouldn't that be counted as cheating? I was hoping to make the sql statement self-sufficient if you get what i mean?